# Actor-Critic one step TD update rule

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic

In [Sutton & Barto](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html)'s book (Chapter $13$), it is stated that the update rule in REINFORCE could be reformated as

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\theta_{t+1}
&=\theta_t+\alpha\left(G_{t:t+1}-\hat{v}(s_t,w)\right)\frac{\nabla\pi(a_t|s_t,\theta_t)}{\pi(a_t|s_t,\theta_t)}\\
&= \theta_t+\alpha\left(r_{t+1}+\gamma\hat{v}(s_{t+1},w)-\hat{v}(s_t,w)\right)\frac{\nabla\pi(a_t|s_t,\theta_t)}{\pi(a_t|s_t,\theta_t)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Essentially replacing $G_{t:t+1}$ with $r_{t+1}+\gamma\hat{v}(s_{t+1},w)$.

Now this transition is unclear to me, and my starting point is that I know we can write a recursive relation for the return which is
\begin{equation}
 G_t=r_{t+1}+\gamma G_{t+1}
\end{equation}
But how do we go from here to the replacement above? isn't $\hat{v}_t(s)=\mathbb{E}_\pi[G_t|s_t=s]$?

It seems that this is all based on the TD error update $V_t\gets V(t)+\alpha\left[r_{t+1}+\gamma V_{t+1} - V_t\right]$, but some of the parts here doesn't add up